# How can I eliminate untracked files from find output?

Tags: find, git

I want to `find` within my project directory, but I'm only looking for files that are tracked by Git.  Is there a command I can use as a filter for the `find` output (or any other means) to limit the results to only the files that Git is tracking?

Example:

```
find . -name '*.postinst' | git-no-untracked
```

What do I use for `git-no-untracked` above?

Comment: `git ls-files | grep 'postinst$'` may do the job

Comment: @Httqm, yes that would work for this simple case (and thanks), but less good when the `find` command has other predicates (such as `-mtime`).  Maybe I might get somewhere by using `comm` to compare `git ls-files` with the `find` output.  I'll have a go at that.

Comment: Comparing using `comm` works, if you're careful to get the paths consistent (i.e. `find .` breaks it because of the leading `./` in the pathnames). I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If switching to `zsh` is an option, you can have the list of *tracked files* in an array:

```
tracked_files=(${(0)"$(git ls-files -z)"})
```

And then do the intersection of the list of files you're interested in like:

```
postinst_files=(**/*.postinst)
tracked_postinst_files=(${postinst_files:*tracked_files})
```

You can do with zsh globs most of what you can do with `find`. For instance, if you want only regular files last modified in the last 2 hours:

```
postinst_files=(**/*.postinst(.mh-2))
```

Or you could directly search for your pattern in the list of tracked files:

```
tracked_postinst_files=(${(M)tracked_files:#*.postinst})
```

Or define a glob qualifier function that checks if the file is in the list of tracked files:

```
istracked() ((${tracked_files[(Ie)${1-$REPLY}]}))

tracked_postinst_files=(**/*.postinst(+istracked))
```

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I'm a Bash user by default/preference, but this certainly gives an insight into what zsh could do for me.

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint to use `git ls-files`, I created a short script to run a command and filter its output using `comm`.  The subtleties are that `comm` requires sorted input, and the lines have to be an exact textual match (so no prefixes such as `./` that the typical `find` command might produce).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

usage()
{
    cat <<EOF
Usage:
   $0 cmd [args... ]

Runs _cmd_ (with arguments, if provided) and filter the output to
files currently tracked by Git.

Example:
    $0 find . -name README -mmin -60

EOF
}

trap 'usage >&2' ERR

case "${1:-}" in
    -h|--help|'-?')
        usage
        exit 0
        ;;
    '')
        usage >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exec comm -12 \
     <("$@" | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 realpath -s --relative-to=. | sort) \
     <(git ls-files | sort)
```

Comment: Cool idea and nice implementation! I'm stealing it for my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one :

```
find . -name '*.postinst' | xargs -I something bash -c 'git ls-files | grep $(basename something)'
```